# Can evaluation show what was evaluated along with results?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting

After I write and evauate the following lines in Mathematica:

```
a = 1
b = 2
x = a + b
```

It will show only the result : 3. I want mathematica to show the following for my output:

x = 1 + 2 = 3

Is it capable of doing this?

There is no similarity between my post and the other.
Can anyone prove that mathematica can do what I asked for?

Comment: Do you want this to happen _all the time_ or only when you ask for it?

Comment: All the time please.

Comment: How about if you just type `13 + 14` without assigning 13 and 14 to variables? Still `13 + 14 = 27`?

Comment: I need to use this for automation, I have a list of variables and then to copy them to word so I can present the results to my professor.

Comment: So after a list of assigning variables and equations I need the program to calculate everything there is and to display them accordingly so I don't have to modify later in word.

Comment: I don't see similarities

Comment: Something like this: `a = 1; b = 2; x := a + b; Fold[HoldForm@Set[#2, #1] &, Reverse@Trace[x, TraceDepth -> 1]] (* x=a+b=1+2=3 *)`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) with [`TraceDepth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraceDepth.html) option set to `1` to get evaluation steps giving whole expression, and format result as you want it. Function performing this actions can be assigned to [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html) to be automatically used for all inputs.

```
ClearAll[showSetSteps]
SetAttributes[showSetSteps, HoldAllComplete]
showSetSteps[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] :=
    With[{trace = Replace[Trace[rhs, TraceDepth -> 1], {} -> {HoldForm@rhs}]},
        lhs = trace[[-1, 1]];
        Fold[HoldForm@Set[#2, #1] &, Append[Reverse@trace, HoldForm@lhs]]
    ]
showSetSteps[expr_] := expr

$Pre = showSetSteps;
```

Which will give:

```
a = 1
b = 2
x = a + b
(* a = 1 *)
(* b = 2 *)
(* x = 1 + 2 = 3 *)
```

---

Depending on what you actually expect to see in the result, you might want to use something else than `Trace`, for example something based on [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html)/[`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html).

```
ClearAll[inactivateActivate]
SetAttributes[inactivateActivate, HoldFirst]
inactivateActivate[expr_, patt_: _, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Inactivate[expr, patt, opts] // Evaluate // HoldForm // Activate //
        {#, # // ReleaseHold} &
```

Which gives:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4;
Trace[(a + b) c^d, TraceDepth -> 1]
inactivateActivate[(a + b) c^d]
(* {3*81, 243} *)
(* {(1 + 2) 3^4, 243} *)

f[x_] := x^2 + 10
Trace[(a + b) f[c] - c, TraceDepth -> 1]
inactivateActivate[(a + b) f[c] - c]
inactivateActivate[(a + b) f[c] - c, h_ /; Context[h] === "System`"]
(* {57 - 3, 54} *)
(* {(1 + 2) f[3] - 3, 54} *)
(* {(1 + 2) 19 - 3, 54} *)
```